# Can a UK tourist visa be also used for business trip?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a UK C visit visa (multiple entry, valid for 6 months) that was issued in June 2017 for tourism. I made one visit, in June 2017, as a tourist. I need to make another visit in October 2017, but this time for an 8-day business trip (meetings and training at company's UK office). Can I use the visa? It is valid until December 2017?

Answer (score 2):

There are some details about exactly what business activities are permitted by the visa at the link below. If you make sure that your planned activities are covered then it appears to me that you would be using the visa correctly. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules  (What you wrote about your trip is not detailed enough to comment on whether it is within the rules)

Comment: Hi, I will be attending meetings with the UK teams and getting training on processes my team in India needs to work on. Would you be in a position to answer now?

Comment: The rules say you can attend meetings and be briefed on the requirements of your UK customer. In my opinion the difference between 'training' and 'briefing' is not significant in this context, but I am not an immigration officer and you should get more expert advice before arranging your travel.

Answer (score -4):

You might not get caught. Or you might get caught, in which case your are in trouble right now, and for the future. It's not something I would risk. Since you met all the requirements to get a visitor visa, you should also be able to meet the requirements for a business visa without problems.

Comment: The new rules allow business activities on a visit visa.

Comment: the thing is UK visa website recommends the same "standard Visitor Visa" for Tourism and short Business Trips. And i already have the standard visitor visa just that i got it for tourism. So, does that make sense to get the same visa again even if i have a valid one? is it required to get it again for short business trip?